# How to feed input to an exe via bat file

Tags: batch-file, exe

Suppose I have a program kn.exe made in Visual Basic which takes in three numbers in text boxes and calculates an index out of them when one clicks the command "Calculate", and displays the calculated number (index) in another text box.

Can I write a .bat file which will have one or several sets of those three numbers and will execute kn.exe, calculate the index and display it (still better if it can write it somewhere)?

It can either execute kn.exe once and feed the several sets of three numbers, or it can start kn.exe for each set of three numbers. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you made `kn.exe`?

Comment: Yes. I have prepared it.

Comment: I can do all the calculations in kn.exe if I want, but that is besides the point. And yes, I mean Windows cmd.exe, not really DOS. I would like to read up about batch file commands.

Comment: You are the one who wrote the program. Not us.  You have complete control of how it works. Program it based on how you want it to function.

Comment: Batch can't interact with GUIs, if that's what you're asking. If your program doesn't take commandline arguments, this isn't possible.

Comment: OK. This is what I wanted to know. Is there some other way another user of kn.exe can automate its use? If not batch files, then can some other script do that? And can that even be made to click commands on kn.exe? Thanks.

Comment: OK. I will read up about AutoHotkey. Sorry, I did not know what one can ask here and what not.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, and only SOMETIMES, you are able to do that with the command redirections or pipes available in the CMD enviroment.

For example, this code will **dir** a patch, search on its results for a specific string, and write it down to a file:

```
dir /b /s "some_patch" | find /i /c ".txt" > "%temp%\dir_log.txt"
```

You can try that with your program. Take it mind the following, taken from ss64.com:

> command > filename        Redirect command output to a file
>
> command >> filename       APPEND into a file
>
> command < filename        Type a text file and pass the text to
>   command
>
> commandA  |  commandB     Pipe the output from commandA into
>   commandB
>
> commandA &  commandB      Run commandA and then run commandB
>   commandA && commandB      Run commandA, if it succeeds then run
>   commandB    commandA || commandB      Run commandA, if it fails then
>   run commandB
>
> commandA && commandB || commandC
>                                If commandA succeeds run commandB, if it fails commandC